# How is this 15?

Tags: javascript

how does this execute to 15??

What is the step by step process that the engine is running?

```
function doSomething(a) {
    function doSomethingElse(a) {
        return a - 1;
    }

    var b;

    b = a + doSomethingElse( a * 2 );

    console.log( (b * 3) );
}

doSomething( 2 ); // 15
```

Comment: Is this just a homework question?

Comment: Are you asking for clarification about what happens with those two variables called `a`? Or is it something else?

Comment: No it's not homework, it's an example in a book and I was just lost. Pointy gave me exactly what I needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: @DylanWatt—it really doesn't matter whether it's homework or not, the OP just wants to know how the logic works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer pointy. To those who are down voting, I am sorry to irritate and offend you. Please forgive me for my transgressions.

Comment: The title doesn't cut it. Try being more descriptive. Edit your question and revise it so that it's clear that this is a JS question. How is this 15? 7+8.

Comment: I think that's where *some* of the down-votes are coming from:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The call to `doSomething()` is made, with `2` as the parameter (bound to `a` in the function).
2. The call to `doSomethingElse()` is made, with `4` (`a * 2`) as the parameter, bound to the symbol `a` in that inner function.
3. The inner function returns `3` (`a - 1`).
4. The `doSomething()` function then adds its `a` (still `2`) to the result, giving `5`, and assigns that to `b`.
5. The `console.log()` call is made, with `15` as the argument (`b * 3`).

Answer (score 4):

Uhhh.... one that works?

```
doSomething(2)
b = 2 + doSomethingElse( 2 * 2 )
b = 2 + ( 4 - 1 )
console.log( 5 * 3 )
```

Comment: I'm really confused why you are implying with your comment, as in the OP's function isn't working properly?